# Use jQuery .click() function with an individual element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the list of tags on an Tumblr blog only when the user clicks on the tags button. For that I use this HTML and jQuery.

**HTML**

```
  <span class="tags-link">Tags</span>
  <ul class="tags">
    <li> <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a> </li>
  </ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tags-link").click(function() {
        $(".tags").slideDown(700, function(){
            //end animation
        });
    });
});
```

Every time I click on the `.tags-link` every `.tags`shows up on the page, and I only want the ones of the post where the user has clicked to be shown. I recently started learning jQuery and I'm a little lost here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.next()` http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
$(this).next(".tags").slideDown(700, function(){
```

Comment: Darn indenting threw me. Have a +1 for spotting that first :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the `tags` that is the next adjacent element only:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tags-link").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".tags").slideDown(700, function(){
            //end animation
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a data attribute on both the span with class "tags-link" and the ul with class "tags".  Then when you click the ".tags-link" element, it will show the ".tags" element with the same data attribute.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="tags-link" data-id="1">Tags</span>
<ul class="tags" data-id="1">
  <li> <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a> </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tags-link").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $(".tags[data-id='" + id + "']").slideDown(700, function(){
            //end animation
        });
    });
});
```